# Write a MySQL query which selects countries having all the vowels present in their name

Tags: mysql

I Have a table called world in which i am supposed to select the name of countries which do not have spaces in between their name and the name contains all the vowels in English alphabet. I tried this but it is not working:

```
select name from world where name not like '% %' and name like '%a%e%i%o%u%'
```

I can't give the table structure and contents here since i don't have access to the entire table's contents. Basically i want to know the regex that i have to use .

An example of the answer is : 'Mozambique'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way, although maybe not the most effective would be:

```
select name from world where name not like '% %' and name like '%a%' and name like '%e%' and name like '%i%' and name like '%o%' and name like '%u%'
```

Not counting uppercase letters as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CONTAINS(column, string)` like that:

```
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE
NOT CONTAINS(name, " ")
AND CONTAINS(name, "a")
AND CONTAINS(name, "e")
AND CONTAINS(name, "i")
AND CONTAINS(name, "o")
AND CONTAINS(name, "u");
```

Or with `LIKE` statement:

```
SELECT name FROM world
WHERE
name NOT LIKE "% %" AND
name LIKE "%a%" AND
name LIKE "%e%" AND
name LIKE "%i%" AND
name LIKE "%o%" AND
name LIKE "%u%";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use *REGEXP* to archive result that you want. The below regular expression pattern means that the name must contains all the vowels in English alphabet.

```
SELECT name 
FROM world
WHERE name REGEXP '[aeiou].*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*[aeiou]'
```